# Adicionar +1 min ao cronômetro regressivo - Com timer já finalizado ou em andamento

Tags: javascript, react, react-native

Cada vez que eu clicar em um botão, quero adicionar +1 min ao timer.

```
<Button
    onPress={this.somarUmMinuto}
    title="Somar 1 minuto"
    color="#007FFF"
    accessibilityLabel="Somar 1 minuto"
/>
```

Código utilizado para definir a contagem regressiva:

```
iniciarCronometro() {
    var intervalId = setInterval(this.somarUmSegundo, 1000);
    this.setState({
      intervalId: intervalId,
    });
}   

somarUmSegundo() {
    let segundos = this.state.contadorSegundo;
    let minutos = this.state.contadorMinuto;

    minutos == 1 || segundos > 0;
    if (segundos == 0) {
      segundos = 59;
      minutos = minutos - 1;
    } else {
      segundos = segundos - 1;
    }

    this.setState({
      contadorSegundo: segundos,
      contadorMinuto: minutos,
    });
}
```

Preciso incrementar o evento para adicionar +1 min ao timer, seja com ele já finalizado ou ainda em andamento na contagem.

Cronometro regressivo tem duração de 1 minuto.

Comment: Veja se esse código ajuda: http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/aBWce/

Comment: Você  já separou os minutos e segundos (contadorMinuto e contadorSegundo), não entendi qual é realmente o problema. Não é só ir no contadorMinuto e incrementar?

Comment: @JrD tentei fazer o incremento direto no contador minuto, mas da erro. Utilizei ´code´ let somar = (this.contadorMinuto +1);

Comment: @PhilipeSaid O seu contadorMinutos está no estado da aplicação, então pra acessá-lo vc precisa usar o this.state. No lugar desse código que vc apresentou tente let somar = this.state.contadorMinuto + 1

Comment: @JrD Continua dando o erro ( undefined is not an object ( evaluating'this.state.contadorMinuto') ).

Comment: @PhilipeSaid Provavelmente vc está perdendo o contexto... faça o bind do seu método para poder acessar o state através do this. Seu onPress ficaria assim onPress={this.somarUmMinuto.bind(this)}

Comment: @JrD O erro não acontece mais. Porém, não executa o incremento do valor.

Comment: @PhilipeSaid Atualize seu código aí por favor para ver o que acontece, esses comentários já estão ficando muito extensos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiramente é preciso fazer um bind no onPress do botão para que seja possível acessar o estado da aplicação, seria dessa forma:

```
onPress={this.somarUmMinuto.bind(this)}
```

Depois é preciso criar a função para esse incremento:

```
somarUmMinuto(){
    this.setState({
        contadorMinuto: this.state.contadorMinuto + 1,
    });
}
```

Comment: Minha função estava completamente errada. Obrigado